# How do I keep a git clone updated?

Tags: linux, git

I am developing a project on my laptop that is to be implemented on my VPS. I am continually making updates on my laptop and pushing them to my git repo, but I am in the dark on how I should keep the clone I made on my server, updated.

When I try to run `git clone <url>` in my directory, it tells me `'file already exists!'` or something along those lines. Do I just delete the entire folder and reclone the repo like that? Or is there a way, other than initiating the directory as git, and creating an upstream, that I can reclone without having to delete everything first?

Comment: just `git pull`

Comment: When i do that, i get an error saying it’s not a git repo or something like that

Comment: Be very, very careful if you deploy an application on your server by using a git clone. Unless you know what you're doing and you're protecting your `.git` properly, you're giving anyone access to the whole source code and its history (possibly including your database password & all). See e.g. https://thenextweb.com/insider/2015/07/27/a-simple-developer-error-is-exposing-private-information-on-thousands-of-websites/. Git isn't meant to be a deployment tool, there are many tools out there for website deployment.

Comment: Thank you for the link, @MatthieuMoy ! It’s actually a private repo that i have :) but i will check that link out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How do I keep a git clone updated?
I generally clone git project.

`git clone git@source.golabs.io:mobile/project-name.git`

and after that I start developing my feature by creating new branch branch. 
so for up to date with remote project you need to checkout to **master** branch. and just do 
**git pull**  and sync your project using `./gradlew clean build`

If your project have submodules- you need to do

```
git submodule update --init --remote --recursive
```

Comment: Thank you for the thorough answer! I’m not doing updating on my deployment server, just looking to reclone without issue but it seems i was using the wrong directory when trying to use git pull...

Answer (score 0):

try to use `git pull`. it will automaticly analyze the difference .And try to fix it

Answer (score 0):

Instead of having to go to your server and pulling, you could setup a listener in order to do the pull for you.

For instance, if you are ushing to GitHub or BitBucket or GitLab, you can setup a webhook ([GitHub webhook](https://developer.github.com/webhooks/), [BitBucket webhook](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/manage-webhooks-735643732.html), [GitLab webhook](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/user/project/integrations/webhooks.html)), and a local listener in order detect the push, and triggger a `git -C /path/to/your/repo pull`.

Comment: Interesting, I’ll have to give this a look

Comment: @M.Gilbert Sur,e but where are you pushing to? Is your remote repo managed by one of the three repo server hosting services I mention?

Comment: Yes, it’s on github :)